# Golang reflect package "is not a type"

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn interfaces and how I can write a single function to work with different types. I came up with this example where I'm finding the maximum value in either a slice of `int` or a slice of `float32`. The code is as follows. I keep getting this error "t is not a type". Could someone please tell me what is wrong and how I might go about fixing it?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

var _ = fmt.Println
var _ = reflect.TypeOf

func maxer(s interface{}) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    t := v.Type()

    maxval := s.(t)[0]
    for _, v := range s.(t)[1:] {
        if v > maxval {
            maxval = v
        }
    }
    return maxval
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(maxer([]int{1, 2, 3, 4}))
    fmt.Println(maxer([]float32{1.1, 2.1, 3.14, 0.1, 2.4}))
```

Comment: `v.Type()` is an object describing a type, not a type, so `s.(t)` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to end up needing to manually handle different types in this case. AFAIK, type assertions must be real types at compile time. Here's my best try in play: http://play.golang.org/p/J8RdHF2MVV

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to learn interfaces and how I can write a single function to work with different types.

then it's probably simpler to avoid the whole reflection package, and just define an interface for your specific purpose.. and types that implement your interface. something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math"


// Homegrown types
type IntArray []int
type Float32Array []float32


// Max defined for type IntArray
func (a IntArray) Max() float64 {
    max := math.MinInt32;
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] > max {
            max = a[i]
        }
    }
    return float64(max)
}


// Max defined for type Float32Array
func (a Float32Array) Max() float64 {
    max := float32(-1 * math.MaxFloat32)
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] > max {
            max = a[i]
        }
    }
    return float64(max)
}


// Define an interface that works for any type
// containing a Max function returning a float64 
type Maxing interface {
    Max() float64
}


// Define a function that works with your interface type
func maxer(m Maxing) float64 {
    return m.Max();
}


func main(){

    // Declare a new IntArray
    i := IntArray([]int{1,2,3})

    // Declare a new Float32Array
    f := Float32Array([]float32{1.0,2.0,3.0})

    // Use any type implementing the Max interface with the 'maxer' func
    fmt.Printf("maxer(IntArray)     = %f\n", maxer(i));
    fmt.Printf("maxer(Float32Array) = %f\n", maxer(f));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [bjarneh's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21532866/4809302). If you want to do this via interfaces, best to avoid reflect. Reflect is not good for comparing values, because you cannot know what type the values are.

My suggestion is to implement something similar to [go's sort interface](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) which allows you to use the function sort on any type.

Implementing it this way would then allow you to get max value for structs or strings, as long as you implemented the functions for them.

[On go playgorund](https://play.golang.org/p/OWtqe0mROg)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Comparable interface {
    Less(i, j int) bool
    Len() int
    Val(i int) interface{}
}

func maxer(s Comparable) (interface{}) {
    if s.Len() == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    maxI := 0
    for i := 1; i < s.Len(); i++ {
        if s.Less(maxI, i) {
            maxI = i
        }
    }
    return s.Val(maxI)
}

type MaxerInt []int
func (m MaxerInt) Len() int {return len(m)}
func (m MaxerInt) Val(i int) interface{} {return m[i]}
func (m MaxerInt) Less(i, j int) bool {return m[i] < m[j]}

type MaxerFloat []float64
func (m MaxerFloat) Len() int {return len(m)}
func (m MaxerFloat) Val(i int) interface{} {return m[i]}
func (m MaxerFloat) Less(i, j int) bool {return m[i] < m[j]}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(maxer(MaxerInt{1, 2, 3, 4}))
    fmt.Println(maxer(MaxerFloat{1.1, 2.1, 3.14, 0.1, 2.4}))
}
```